# Conditional Key Remapping AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to remap the 'j' key so that it presses n when ergo is true, or y when it is false with AutoHotKey. When I remap normally using "j::n" for example, shift+j outputs a capital N, and so do other modifiers with the 'j' key. However, my code below only works when the letters are pressed without modifiers. Is there a way to get around this, and conditionally remap keys with AutoHotKey?

```
j::
    if (ergo) ;inverted use of the ergo variable to make the code more efficient
        Send {n}
    else
        Send {y}
return
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only want to wrap characters which have a [special meaning](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#keynames) in a send command in `{ }`. Basically escaping, if you're familiar with that what is.
So you don't want to wrap <kbd>n</kbd> or <kbd>y</kbd> in `{ }`. It can even result in [undesired behavior](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#AZ).

There are quite a few approaches for this. Can't say which is best, since don't know what your full script is like.
I'll present two options that I'd guess to be most likely best approaches for you.

---

Firstly, the send command way like you tried. Just doing it right:

```
*j::
    if (ergo)
        SendInput, {Blind}n
    else
        SendInput, {Blind}y
return
```

So, usage of the `*`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#wildcard)</sup> modifier so the hotkey works even if extra modifiers are being held down.
And then usage of the [blind send mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#blind) so which ever modifier keys you may be holding when triggering the hotkey will not be released.
Also switched over to [SendInput](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) due to it being the recommended faster and more reliable send mode.

---

Second way would be creating a context sensitive hotkey with `#If`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm)</sup>.

```
#If, ergo
j::n
#If
j::y
```

This is a convenient and easy approach. But could possibly result in other problems.
Why? Well `#If` comes with some downsides which you can read more about [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm#General_Remarks), but long story short:
You likely wont have any trouble unless you have a more complicated script.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I used the second way because it does not interfere with the rest of my code, and there are less lines.

Answer (score 1):

> When I remap normally using "j::n" for example, shift+j outputs a capital N, and so do other modifiers with the 'j' key. **However, my code below only works when the letters are pressed without modifiers**.

Looks like you are looking for the Wildcard `*` modifier.

From the [docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm):

> Wildcard: Fire the hotkey even if extra modifiers are being held down. This is often used in conjunction with remapping keys or buttons.

So after this change, your code  would look something like:

```
*j::
    if (ergo) ;inverted use of the ergo variable to make the code more efficient
        Send {n}
    else
        Send {y}
return
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That doesn't exactly solve my problem though. With your code, when I press shift and 'J', it still outputs a lower case letter 'n'. What I want it to do is output a capital letter 'N' when I press shift and 'J'.